# How to provide a customized error message if Cmake find_package cannot find a package?

Tags: cmake

suppose a `CMakeList.txt` has the line `find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core)`

however, the user doesn't configure the environment with QT correctly, so Cmake will just show that it cannot find Qt6.

I would like to provide a customized message like "Cannot find Qt6, maybe try `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/qt/6.2.3/macos`"

is it possible to achieve the goal?

Comment: Pass QUIET parameter to the `find_package` call, so it won't print standard phrases like "Cannot find Qt6". After calling for `find_package` checks `Qt6_FOUND` variable and print a message according to it (TRUE means the package has been found, FALSE means the package hasn't been found).

Comment: @Tsyvarev it's my answer, would you like to put it to the answer area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `QUIET` to `find_package` call you could disable standard message. After the call you could check value of `*_FOUND` variable for determine, whether `find_package` has been succeeded or not, and print corresponding message. Something like that:

```cmake
find_package(Qt6 QUIET COMPONENTS Core)
if (Qt6_FOUND)
  # Success
  message(STATUS "Found Qt6")
else()
  # Fail
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Qt6, maybe try 'cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/qt/6.2.3/macos'")
endif()
```

In the `else` branch the keyword `FATAL_ERROR` ensures that CMake will stop executing after printing the message. This is a standard workflow for projects when required dependencies are not found. However, if your project is developed to work without Qt6 too, you could omit `FATAL_ERROR` and use any other keyword for [message](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) call.